# Trigger to update parent record by child record . Please review my code and let me know where it went wrong

Tags: trigger

```
    public static void Afterupdate(list<Contact> lstcon, Map<id,Contact> mapcont)
    {
        Map<id,String> accid = new Map<id,String>();
        list<Contact> updatedcont = new list<Contact>();
        for(Contact cc : lstcon)
        {
            if(cc.description != mapcont.get(cc.id).description)
            {
                accid.put(cc.AccountId,cc.Description);
            }
        }
        
        List<Account> lstfinalacc = new List<Account>();
        List<Account> lstacc = [select id,Description from Account where id IN : accid.keyset()];
        System.debug(lstacc);
        for( Account aa : lstacc )
        {
            if(accid.containsKey(aa.Id))
            {
               
                aa.Description = accid.get(aa.id);
                
                system.debug(aa.Description);
            
                lstfinalacc.add(aa);
                
            }
            
        }
        
        update lstfinalacc;
        
    }
```

Comment: What went wrong?

Comment: Basic advice: don't just throw in empty lines for the hell of it (referring to the `if` in the second loop). Also, be consistent in your code style. `Map` is capitalized but `list` isn't? There should be a space between commas and the thing that comes after (`Map<Id, String>`, `SELECT Id, Description...`, etc...). Class and Type names should start with a capital letter (specifically `Id` in your code, using "PascalCase" to be more precise). Method names should start with a lowercase letter (e.g. `afterUpdate`, the style here is "camelCase").

Comment: Your variable names are also rather poor. `accid` is misleading because it doesn't have any indication that it's a map. `contactDescriptionByAccountId` is much more informative. Not a big issue here because the code is pretty short, but maintaining discipline and doing it anyway means it's more likely you'd do it when/where it does matter.

Answer (score 1):

Without the full context and an explanation of what you were told was wrong, it's difficult to say what your code should look like (at least if you want an accurate answer, that is).

That said, and without doing 100% of your work for you, I can say that everything after the first `for` loop in your code is unnecessary (save for the dml statement at the end).

If you have the Id of an SObject, you do not need to query for that record to be able to update it. You can simply specify the Id of the target record in the constructor for that object.

As an example (and I'm avoiding working with Contacts/Accounts on purpose here)

```java
// Still need a map so we can handle the situation where we work on multiple
//   OLIs for a single Opportunity.
// If you would just use a List, you'd be liable to run into a "duplicate
//   Id in list" error
Map<Id, Opportunity> oppMapForUpdate = new Map<Id, Opportunity>();

// As long as givenOLIList isn't null, we don't need to perform any checks
// An empty list is not the same as null, and is perfectly fine
for(OpportunityLineItem oli : givenOLIList) {
    Opportunity parentRecord = new Opportunity(
        // Assigning the Id in the constructor
        // This is the important part, and allows us to avoid a query
        Id = oli.OpportunityId,
        Description = oli.Id
    );

    // If we happen to encounter the same OpportunityId more than once
    //   this will simply overwrite the previous data in the map
    // The last time we encounter an OpportunityId dictates which OLI Id
    //   actually ends up on the Opportunity
    oppMapForUpdate.put(oli.OpportunityId, parentRecord);
}

update oppMapForUpdate.values();
```

Answer (score -2):

1. **`Sring Comparison`**: Instead of using != for String comparison, you should use the != operator to compare strings. Use the
   String.equals() method for String comparison. Change this line:

> if(cc.description != mapcont.get(cc.id).description)

to

> if (!cc.description.equals(mapcont.get(cc.id).description))

2. **Account Update Logic:**
   It's good to verify if the lstfinalacc list is not empty before attempting to update the accounts.

> if (!lstfinalacc.isEmpty()) {
> update lstfinalacc;
> }

3. **Avoiding Null Pointer Exception:**
   It's good practice to check if mapcont.get(cc.id) returns a non-null value before accessing its properties.

> if (cc.description != null && mapcont.get(cc.id) != null && !cc.description.equals(mapcont.get(cc.id).description)) {
> accid.put(cc.AccountId, cc.Description);
> }

Comment: The first point makes an invalid assertion (both approaches are fine, `!=` is case-insensitive while String's `.equals()` is case-sensitive). The second point is just plain wrong and poor style (dml on an empty list is a no-op, doesn't even consume a dml statement for the governor limit). The third point has at least some merit. Probably not an actual concern in this code, but if it is, you could simply use the Safe Navigation Operator `?.` instead of getting data from the map again.

Comment: tl;dr: This answer is bad advice, and nobody should follow it.

Comment: Considering this user's other two answers (at time of writing), this may have also been generated by A.I.. In which case, this is a perfect example for why A.I. is not allowed here (and should not be used to try to fill large gaps in knowledge).

Comment: This is my coding suggestion, reflecting my personal approach. While not every answer may have been generated by AI, I appreciate and respect your input. I believe the suggestions I've provided are valuable and well-considered.